# How to solve sensitive case url issue whit @file_get_contents using php?

Tags: php

How to solve sensitive case url issue whit `@file_get_contents` using php ?

it's work good when use lower case url `example.com`

like this code

```
$json = @file_get_contents("https://www.example.com/test.php?word=example.biz", true);
```

but not work when use upper case with first url `Example.com`

like this code

```
$json = @file_get_contents("https://www.Example.com/test.php?word=example.biz", true);
```

How to solve this issue for work good on lower and upper case ?

Comment: `strtolower` url before use

Answer (score 0):

all domains are always in lowercase but querystring and their path may be in upper case. So we can't convert entire url to lowercase but only domain.

So following code will only convert domain to lowercase and keep rest of path and querystring components as is.

```
<?php

$url = "https://www.Example.com/test.php?word=example.biz";


$parse_url = parse_url($url);

//print_r($parse_url);die;

$new_url = $parse_url['scheme'].'://'.strtolower($parse_url['host']).$parse_url['path'].'?'.$parse_url['query'];




$json = @file_get_contents($new_url, true);

?>
```